# Updating an object in child class, doesn't update the object inside List<T> in the base class

Tags: c#, list, pass-by-reference

I have the following classes:

```
public class DrawableComplexEntity2D
{
    public List<GameComponent> Components { get; set; }

    // anothers properties, constructor, methods...
}

public class BoardCell : DrawableComplexEntity2D
{
    public GoalPersonGroup GoalPersonGroup { get; set; }

    public void CreateGoalPersonGroup(Goal groupType)
    {
        this.GoalPersonGroup = new GoalPersonGroup(groupType)
        base.Components.Add(this.GoalPersonGroup);
    }
}
```

So, when i do:

```
BoardCell cell1 = new BoardCell();
cell1.CreateGoalPersonGroup(Goal.Type1);

BoardCell cell2 = new BoardCell();
cell2.CreateGoalPersonGroup(Goal.Type2);

cell1.GoalPersonGroup = cell2.GoalPersonGroup;
```

When i update the cell1.GoalPersonGroup with cell2.GoalPersonGroup, the cell1.GoalPersonGroup is updated, but the cell1.GoalPersonGroup that is inside of the base.Components of cell1 doesn`t change and still the value of cell1 instead cell2. Why?

Comment: Why should it change, if you haven't written the code to change it?

Comment: When i add a object inside a List<T> what i add isn`t the reference o the object?

Comment: What you add to a `List<T>` *is* a reference to the *object*, but not a reference to a property. You're replacing the property with a reference to a completely separate object. The `Components` list still holds a reference to the original object, because that's what you added to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lists, as with all other variables, contain *values*. With a reference type (which I'm assuming `GoalPersonGroup` is), the *value* is a *reference*. If I have the following:

```
object a = ...;
object b = ...;

a = b;
```

All I've done is take the *value* of `b` (which is a reference) and copied that value to `a`. In the case of a reference type, I can perform operations *on* that value (like calling `a.SomeProperty = "foo";`) and those same changes in state will be reflected anywhere in the program where that particular reference is stored in a variable. In other words, if I were to inspect the value of `b.SomeProperty`, it would be `"foo"`.

However, *changing* the value in the variable does not affect other variables that point to that value (except in the case of a `ref` parameter).

You've added a value that points to a reference to your `List`. You've also assigned that same value to a property. These two distinct memory locations contain the same value, and thus point to the same actual object. But later you're just reassigning the value of the property, which means that it now has a *different* value than what's stored in the list.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are getting confused with references. Assigning a reference variable assigns the thing that is referenced.

eg

```
string str1 = new String("Hello");   //str1 has a reference to "Hello"
string basestr = str1;               //basestr has a reference to "Hello" (NOT str1)

string str2 = new String("Goodbye"); //str2 has a reference to "Goodbye"
str1 = str2;                         //str1 has a reference to "Goodbye" (basestr still = hello)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are only changing the reference in the property `cell1.GoalPersonGroup`, not the one you have added to `base.Components`. To fix this, you'll have to add code in the setter of `GoalPersonGroup` to do what you want.

Comment: When i add a object inside a List<T> what i add isn`t the reference o the object?

Comment: @ViniciusOttoni: You've added a value, which in the case of reference types is a *reference*. But changing that value later does not affect the reference or any other variables that happen to have the same value.